ASP.NET MVC 5 - render views from subfolders
We have a very basic ASP.NET MVC project that includes an EmployeeController and a StudentController. In the Views folder, we have the corresponding Employee and Student folders.
In the Employees view folder are the following files:
~/View/Employee/Index.cshtml
~/View/Employee/PageNotFound.cshtml
~/View/Employee/Test.cshtml

In the Student view folder, I have these files:
~/View/Student/Index.cshtml
~/View/Student/PageNotFound.cshtml
~/View/Student/Test.cshtml
~/View/Student/About/Index.cshtml

Regarding the Student views, there is no About controller. The reason for this is that there is a CMS that publishes .cshtml files (possibly in subfolders) to both Student and Employee view folders on the web server.
So I need a way to load any view in any subfolder of ~Views/Student in the StudentController. I found a number of articles that describe how this can be done. I discovered that a view does not need a specific controller as I found this code:
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
{
    try
    {
        this.View(actionName).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException )
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Student/PageNotFound");
    }
}

So even though there is no Test action on the StudentController, I can render https://localhost:44367/Student/Test via the HandleUnknownAction() method.
The problems begin when trying to render views in subfolders - like https://localhost:44367/Student/About/Index.cshtml.
This article here Can I specify a custom location to "search for views" in ASP.NET MVC? addresses this situation so I tried:
System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine rve = (RazorViewEngine)ViewEngines.Engines
          .Where(e => e.GetType() == typeof(RazorViewEngine))
          .FirstOrDefault();

string[] additionalPartialViewLocations = new[] 
         {
             "~/Views/Student/About/{0}.cshtml"
         };

if (rve != null)
{
    rve.PartialViewLocationFormats = rve.PartialViewLocationFormats
              .Union(additionalPartialViewLocations)
              .ToArray();

    rve.ViewLocationFormats = rve.ViewLocationFormats
              .Union(additionalPartialViewLocations)
              .ToArray();
}

I hard-coded the ~/Views/Student/About/{0}.cshtml path hoping to say "Look in this folder". Still get a 404 at https://localhost:44367/Student/About/Index.cshtml.
I debugged HandleUnknownAction() and noticed that the {string actionName} parameter is About for this url, I guess I expected it to be Index.
Then I thought I could alter the routing and came up with this in the RouteConfig.cs:
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Student",
            url: "Student/{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Index" }
        );

Any request below Student gets mapped to the one Index action in StudentController. This gets me closer to what I'm looking for, but now I'm responsible for looking up physical files from urls, seeing if they exist, redirecting to PageNotFound.cshmtl if not etc.
I feel like this defeats the whole purpose of ASP.NET MVC.
Is this a routing issue then? Do I need a custom RazorViewEngine? We expect to have many .cshtml files grouped into subfolders under Student and Employee view folders, I need to load these views somehow. Not unreasonable to expect something like ~Views/Student/About/Subfolder1/Subfolder2/Applying.cshtml
Appreciate any help on this!

DId I understand it correctly - you want to add new cshtml files during the runtime? And app should pick them up dynamically?

Michal, yes that's exactly the scenario. I'm not convinced that mvc is the right architecture for this, yet we're close to having a workable solution so interested in seeing it through.
